# How to fetch the Data of First Column as Row to the Header and Last column as Row Belongs to header in SQL Query?

Tags: sql

I have 3 table in database 1.Warehouse, 2.Product, 3. Stock and i want to fetch the Data from these three Table like. 
Frirst Column are the Warehouses names want be the header of available Quantity left in Stock. 
Second Column is The Product Names which can not be duplicated.
Third Column is Available Quantity in Stock which have to convert as row along with First Column warehouse names.

I have tried only with group by clause but i didn't get my desire result
 out

```
Warehouse Name   |  Product Name   Available Quantity
Warehouse 1      |   Shampoo         50
Warehouse 2      |   Shampoo         100
Warehouse 3      |   Shampoo         40
Warehouse 1      |   Soup           50
Warehouse 2      |   Soup           80
Warehouse 3      |   Soup           120
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I would be helpful if you included the original tables with schema and data. People need to be able to reproduce your question. Also, it seems you are using MySQL, but I'm not sure. Please be specific.

Comment: @user2065377 Can you please help me recording this problem

Comment: thank you so much for reply it's sql server it's already solved